# Automatically Post to Google + Business Page

Tags: php, google-api, google-plus, google-api-php-client, google-api-client

Is it possible to post to Google + through PHP using some kind of API? I've read many conflicting statements on various places, including here on SO.

I've read that you need an analytics account, that you need to add a website to your page, that it isn't possible, that it's a closed service and you must apply, that you need your GMail username & password .etc.

Just really looking for a bit of clarity really. Found [this](https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client), but I'm not sure if it allows this functionality. The lack of documentation really makes it quite daunting looking into this as well, there is literally nothing I can find at all.

Another option I've found appears to work, however it was from a website where you must pay to download the API. I'm genuinely not sure how or if it can be done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google restrict this API to whitelisted partners and companies through https://developers.google.com/+/web/api/rest/pages-signup

You could however use a third party script such as https://gist.github.com/zachbrowne/3301749 which handles the posting as if it was a logged in front end user rather than a direct API update flow.